# Full text search jOOQ

Tags: mysql, jooq

I want to make use of full text search, so I upgraded to MySQL 5.6 (InnoDB support).
It all works, but now I want to add full text search to a jOOQ query, but I cannot find how to. Is it included in the API? If not can I add conditions in plain sql to a `SelectQuery` ? Or how should I solve this?

I'm using version 2.3.2 of jOOQ

---

EDIT:

Ok apparently I can add plain SQL by using `Factory.condition(String sql)`, but I'm still wondering if it's included in the API

Comment: *"I'm using version 2.3.2 of jOOQ"* - Why? :-)

Comment: Yes I know, we should look into updating to the latest version ;)

Comment: You will be able to derive only happiness from it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jOOQ doesn't have support for MySQL full text search functions (yet, as of jOOQ 3.3). It's on the roadmap as issue [#1706](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1706).

Resorting to [plain SQL](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/) (as you did), is the way to go forward.